# Read string from USB HID RFID Reader with Java

Tags: java, usb, usb4java

I'm trying to read a String from a via USB connected RFID-Reader. The Reader is recognized correctly inside my appliaction. But I do not know how to read the transferred characters into a String.

If I do not detach the device, the String is printed like by a Keyboard (as you would expect from a HID). What I want is to catch that String inside my Java application only. This is the reason why I detach the USB device.

For example my application prints '"''#$&' to the console (see code below)  or something like this

[0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 34, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

But what I wanted to read is 05006790.

I think that there is a stupid false in my attempt. I hope that someone can help me to figure out how I have to read the Bytes into a String correctly.

Thank you very much.

CODE FOLLOWS HERE

```
Context context = new Context();
    int result = LibUsb.init(context);

    DeviceList list = new DeviceList();
    result = LibUsb.getDeviceList(context, list);

    for (Device device: list)
    {
        int address = LibUsb.getDeviceAddress(device);
        int busNumber = LibUsb.getBusNumber(device);

        DeviceDescriptor descriptor = new DeviceDescriptor();
        DeviceHandle handle = new DeviceHandle();

        int resultOpen = LibUsb.open(device, handle);
        // if (resultOpen < 0) // handle = null;

        int resultDescriptor = LibUsb.getDeviceDescriptor(device, descriptor);
        // if (resultDescriptor< 0) // handle = null;

        if(descriptor.idVendor() == 0x8ff && descriptor.idProduct() == 0x0009)
        {
            System.out.println("found");
            LibUsb.detachKernelDriver(handle, 0);
        }
    }

    UsbServices services = UsbHostManager.getUsbServices();
    UsbDevice deviceHigh = findDevice(services.getRootUsbHub(), (short) 0x8ff, (short) 0x0009);


    if(deviceHigh != null)
    {
        System.out.println("found high");

        UsbConfiguration configuration = deviceHigh.getActiveUsbConfiguration();
        UsbInterface iface = configuration.getUsbInterface((byte) 0x00);

        iface.claim();

        UsbEndpoint endpoint = iface.getUsbEndpoint((byte) 0x81);
        UsbPipe pipe = endpoint.getUsbPipe();

        pipe.open();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
        int rx = 0;
        rx = pipe.syncSubmit(buffer);

        System.out.printf("%d bytes received\n", rx);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buffer));

        iface.release();
    }
```

Comment: What kind of device you are connecting? if your device have the ft232 chip, you need first set it to correct speed, parity and stop bits (it is a bridge rs232-usb). The output looks like you have this case, reading some comm port with bad speed/other settings.

Comment: Hmmm ... I think that I might have not enough knowledge about USB to answer correctly.
The device is a RFID reader (ID 08ff:0009 AuthenTec, Inc.) directly connected to USB port